# Can't update Android Studio to 2.0 getting java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting the error when trying to update failed to apply patch.

Temp directory: `C:\Users\hackx\AppData\Local\Temp\`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\hackx\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\log\idea.updater.files.tmp.0\temp.tmp.1\gradle\gradle-2.8\src\diagnostics\org\gradle\api\tasks\diagnostics\htmldependencyreport\d.png
(The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(NativeMethod)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:156)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copyStreamToFile(Utils.java:127)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copy(Utils.java:97)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copy(Utils.java:91)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copy(Utils.java:91)
at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.doBackup(DeleteAction.java:52)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.backup(PatchAction.java:190)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch$2.forEach(Patch.java:295)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:360)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:291)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:75)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:280)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:17)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner$1.execute(Runner.java:246)
at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I had same error on a different file last night. No obvious changes to my machine and the patch applied successfully just now; maybe you'll have the similar luck.

Comment: Antivirus or Windows Defender may cause this. Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38194603/1911652) answer if it can help you.