# Android Studio (1.5.1 to 2.1.2) failed to apply patch (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I've been trying to upgrade Android Studio from 1.5.1 to 2.1.2 and it keeps giving me the java.io.FileNotFoundException, and that "(The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)".

(see below)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\name\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\log\idea.updater.files.tmp.0\temp.tmp.1\gradle\gradle-2.8\docs\dsl\org.gradle.api.plugins.ApplicationPluginConvention.html (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
```

Please help!

*Note: I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its too late to answer this. I faced this problem some time back and solved it just by disabling real-time protection of  Windows Defender. What happens here is system protection tools (antivirus, windows defender etc) deletes the necessary installation files causing this trouble.

To disable Windows defender:

1. Go to control panel (Run -> control )
2. From Control Panel\All Control Panel Items find out and launch Windows Defender (Alternatively you can check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg131918.aspx) link how to run it direct from command line)
3. In Windows Defender go to Settings->Real-time protection
4. Check off "Turn on real-time protection"

Now run the upgrade again. It will go through successfully. Once done with upgrade, turn on real-time protection again.

If not Windows Defender, you can try turning off antivirus protection at the time of upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this next time. I fixed the problem by going to the website and downloading AS again.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @atul is correct, however, I am adding settings if you have installed **"Windows Security Essentials"**

> You can change settings in Microsoft Security Essentials and turn off
>   "Real-time" protection but it will cause the same error if turned on
>   again.

In order to overcome the problem once for all you need to add your Android project in the excluded list, images for description below

**Step 1: Go to Microsoft Security Essentials**

[image: Go to Microsoft Security Essentials]

**Step 2: Click on "Exclude files and locations"**

and click over "Browse" to select Android project folder

[image: Click on "Exclude files and locations]

**Step 3: Click "Add" and "Save Changes"**

[image: Click "Add" and "Save Changes"]

**Note:** This setting may leave your project folder prone to unknown viruses.